# How to find non compliant rows in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to find and segregate some rows whose certain columns don't follow certain pattern. I found the following example from databricks document to identify and check column values are integer or not and write the bad records into json file.

I want to identify whether one column values are like 1,245.00 and bad records will be like 1.245,00.
The values can vary the number of digits and just want to check whether data follows patter like 1,245.00 in pyspark.

Sometimes in the raw data, commas and dots are inter changed.

Can someone tell me how to collect such records in badrecordpath as in the following example?

```
// Creates a json file containing both parsable and corrupted records
Seq("""{"a": 1, "b": 2}""", """{bad-record""").toDF().write.text("/tmp/input/jsonFile")

val df = spark.read
  .option("badRecordsPath", "/tmp/badRecordsPath")
  .schema("a int, b int")
  .json("/tmp/input/jsonFile")

df.show()
```

The above example is in scala and am looking for pyspark solution if possible.  Thanks.

Comment: can you post some sample input data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Please find some examples as below (with 2 last decimal points)

```
1,245.00 
3,5000.80
6.700,00
5.7364732.20
4,500,600.00
```

dataframe with following data (with compliance) should have dot and two digits decimals

```
1,245.00 
3,5000.80
4,500,600.00
```

Illegal data points should be kept in badRecordsPath (a comma before the decimal point)

```
6.700,00
5.7364732,20
```

Thanks